# Items Source in Datagrid are NULL Firebase

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, collections, observablecollection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZVue.png)i am doing a code in c# WPF where i want to update automatically my datagrid if my database in firebase have changes. For that reason i am using the nuget Firebase.Donet and i work with this code:

```
  var observable = a.BaseDatos().Child("Alquileres").AsObservable<eAlquiler>();
            dtCLiente.ItemsSource = observable.ObserveOnDispatcher().AsObservableCollection();
```

And works ok the datagrid changes automatically but the problem is when i dont have elements in my database the itemsSource have a problem beacuse is null. Please Help me

Comment: `the problem is when i dont have elements in my database the itemsSource have a problem beacuse is null`, if you don't have elements in the db your items source will be null and it should be, what do you expect it to be?

Comment: Hi, that happen that the windows close and give a error System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: The problem is my datagrid, when the itemsSource is null. this close and give me an error

Comment: `windows close and give a error System.ArgumentNullException`, can you provide that code if you have it?

Comment: If you put a break point in there, what do you get as observable? You can probably just put a null check in there. Set the itemssource to null or an empty collection if you have nothing.

Comment: private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dtCLiente.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            var observable = a.BaseDatos().Child("Alquileres").AsObservable<eAlquiler>();
            dtCLiente.ItemsSource = observable.ObserveOnDispatcher().AsObservableCollection();
         
          
        }

Comment: Please look the photo in the question. iam add now